# How to select an input value from a specific form using JQuery, when form id is a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

Let's say I have two forms with the same textbox input on both:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="phone_number">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2">
<input type="text" name="phone_number">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Using JQuery, I want to select the input value for phone_number from form2, using a variable in the selector to reference form2, eg:

The value 'form2' is represented as variable 'someform' **(THIS DOESN'T WORK):**

```
$("#" + someform input[name=phone_number]").val();
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of my question. I knew how to use a variable in a selector, what I didn't know was how to select a form field when the form id is a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
$('#'+someform).find('input[name=phone_number]').val();
```